# How to find the minimum value of $\sum _{i=1}^n\min (a_i,2i-1)$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, $a_1,a_2,\ldots ,a_n$ is a permutation of $1,2,\ldots ,n$, try to find the minimum value of $\sum _{i=1}^n\min (a_i,2i-1)$.

I have programmed and calculated the situations of $n$ from $1$ to $8$, and found that the minimum value $\left \lceil \frac{n(n+1)}{3}\right \rceil$ (**This answer is my guess. I put the first eight items into OEIS, and then guess it should be the right answer. After all, it is very concise.**) can be obtained when the  permutation is $n,n-1,\ldots ,2,1$. But I can not  prove it, and I want to know how many permutations can take the minimum value when taking $n$.

Comment: Unsure if the following idea will be of any assistance.  Let $S$ be the specific sum, where the minimum is taken, for each pair.  Let $T$ denote the corresponding sum, where the maximum is taken, for each pair.  Then, you must have that regardless of how the elements are permuted, $T \geq S$ and $(S + T)$ is a constant.  That is $(S + T)$ will be the same, regardless of how the elements are permuted. So, the idea is that you want to maximize $(T - S)$.  Again, I am unsure whether this idea will lead anywhere.

Comment: A standard-sneaky way of proving that the permutation $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}=\{n,n-1,\dots,1\}$ gives the minimum: given any permutation $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$, if there exists $i<j$ such that $a_i<a_j$, consider the same permutation but with $a_i$ and $a_j$ interchanged, and show that that makes the value of the sum decrease or stay the same.